# How is the partition decided in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS2 Ardent, the default partition used is `rt/`. I recently got a ROS2 publisher code snippet where nothing was mentioned about the partition. So I assumed it to be `rt/` but when I ran the RTI Admin Console, I got to know that the partition used was `rt/ros`.

Where do I alter it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299112/how-is-the-partition-decided-in-ros2-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Until ROS Bouncy, the full topic names were constructed as follow:
`<ROS_PREFIX>/<NAMESPACE>/<TOPIC_NAME>` where:

`ROS_PREFIX` is one of the prefixes defined [here](https://github.com/ros2/design/blob/9d971dd155be6e9c74f4e5fa4d7613a946b7d7d5/articles/140_topic_and_service_name_mapping.md#ros-specific-namespace-prefix)

Some examples can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/design/blob/9d971dd155be6e9c74f4e5fa4d7613a946b7d7d5/articles/140_topic_and_service_name_mapping.md#examples-of-ros-names-to-dds-concepts)

The partition value is everything before the last forward slash. In you case I assume that the namespace is `ros`, resulting in a fully qualified topic name `rt/ros/my_topic`. This leads to the partition `rt/ros` and the topic name `my_topic`.

Note that as of ROS Bouncy the partitions [are not used anymore](https://github.com/ros2/design/pull/170) so for the topic `rt/ros/my_topic` the partition will be an empty string and the DDS topic name will be `rt/ros/my_topic`

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2